# PHP Input Form to Database Questions

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, dropdown

I'm working on something that is likely simple, but boggling my mind, as I'm relatively new to PHP and am trying to fine tune my skills.

So basically what I'm looking to have done is to have a form where a user inputs information into text boxes, picks something from a drop down list, and also chooses yes or no in a radio button, and submits.

Once the submission happens, where I'm stuck is the following:

A) What do I type in my "create.php" code that puts the information from the text boxes, selection from the drop down list, and choice picked in the radio button into the database? I know how to get the text area characters into it, and my sample code below reflects that, but how do options selected from a drop down list and radio button fit in?

and B) I am hoping that each inputted set of values each have an ability to be deleted by ONLY myself or the user that inputted it. Basically, create a password for each entry.

I'm now pasting my code. First, here is the form that is in the HTML document:

```
<div id="post form"><form action="create.php" method="post">
Your Information<br />
Name <input type="text" name="name" ><br />
E-mail <input type="text" name="email" ><br />
Phone <input type="text" name="phone" ><br />

<br />Other Information<br />
Location <input type="text" name="location" ><br />
Age <input type="text" name="age" ><br />
Budget <input type="text" name="price" ><br />
<br />Number of Cars
<select name="formCars">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
<option value="5">Five</option>
<option value="6">Six</option>
<option value="7">Seven</option>
<option value="8">Eight</option>
<option value="9">Nine</option>
<option value="10">Ten</option>
</select>
<br />Number of Bicycles
<select name="formBicycles">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
<option value="5">Five</option>
<option value="6">Six</option>
<option value="7">Seven</option>
<option value="8">Eight</option>
<option value="9">Nine</option>
<option value="10">Ten</option>
</select>
<br />What You Drive
<select name="formType">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="C">Car</option>
<option value="T">Truck</option>
<option value="M">Motorcycle</option>
<option value="V">Van</option>
</select><br />
<br />Are You Happy With It?
<input type="radio" name="fix" value="Yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="fix" value="No" />No
<br />
<br /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Post" /><br />
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP code I've got so far:

```
<?php

echo "<a href='index.html'><img src='header.png' border=0></a>";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","123456","sampleTable");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("123456", $con);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Information
(
name varchar(50),
email varchar(50),
phone varchar(10),
location varchar(50),
age varchar(50),
price varchar(50),
)";

mysql_query($sql,$con);

mysql_select_db("123456", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO information (name, email, phone, location, age, 
price)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[location]',
'$_POST[age]','$_POST[price]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "<br />";

echo "Thanks for posting!";

echo "<br />";

echo "<p><a href='index.html'>Back</a>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thank you all so much for your help! Again, newbie-ish here, so detailed help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the `select` list do you want the text value or the integer value stored? Don't use `mysql_` functions, use `pdo` or `mysqli` this is open to SQL injections. `$_POST['formCars']` should have one of your selects, look at that. Do the same for radios `$_POST['fix']`..

Comment: The integer value can just be stored. And in terms of your other suggestions, I guess I'm not really sure how to re-write this without mysql.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It sounds like I've been approaching this all wrong. That being said, does anyone have tutorials that could lead me to accomplishing what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

Here is some information. Do you know how can you check your post data ?

```
<?php
// After post you can use dump functions 
var_dump($_POST);
// or you can use array export for print
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

You will see input type text, select option value or input radio values same data structure. But if they are not array definition. For example;

```
<form .... method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" value="audi">
<input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" value="vw">
</form>
```

Cars will be array because name has `[]`

Second question a little interesting. Because you don't need a password for every entity normally. When you use user session, you can use only user id as a field in your form table. If users has a session ( logged ) and his user id same with form data record id you can show delete button.

Here is a user management sample here https://daveismyname.blog/login-and-registration-system-with-php

By the way you don't need the create table for every request for your php file.

Another important advice is do not use mysql_* functions. You can use mysqli_* functions or you can use PDO.

Comment: Thank you, you answered my second question. That's really all I wanted to do was for the user who inputted data to be able to delete it themselves also. For example, if they typed their name wrong and hit submit.

In terms of everything else, I'm still a little confused. As mentioned to the gentleman above, I'm not really sure how to reconfigure or re-write this not using mysql.

Comment: A login system made by some guy named Dave is really not something you should be using.

Comment: I think I wrote enough. I didn't say use David's codes. I said it's a sample. "Thanks" for negative points guys.